# Whole text is copied to the right side in react native code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[image: after code execute]

Now it is on the left side. How to copy the same text to the right even
and how can I style the button and style the text input more colorful and fonts bigger?

Here the example of what I want:

[image]

Here is what I have tried

```js
<View style={StyleSheet.row}>
    <Text>GAME 10</Text>
    <TextInput
      placeholder="GAME 10"
      underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
      style={StyleSheet.TextInputStyleClass}
    />
</View>
<View style={StyleSheet.row}>
  <Text>TOTAL TEAM 1:</Text>
  <TextInput
    placeholder="TOTAL"
    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
    style={StyleSheet.TextInputStyleClass}
  />
</View>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onButtonPress}>
  <Text>ADD</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: please show us your efforts

Answer (score 0):

You can move the text into a component, then just render the component twice:

```
export default class Text extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <View style={StyleSheet.row}>
                    <Text>
                        GAME 10
                    </Text>
                    <TextInput  placeholder="GAME 10" underlineColorAndroid='transparent' style={StyleSheet.TextInputStyleClass} />
                </View>


                <View style={StyleSheet.row}>
                    <Text>
                        TOTAL TEAM 1:
                    </Text>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="TOTAL"
                        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                        style={StyleSheet.TextInputStyleClass}
                    />

                </View>


                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onButtonPress}>
                    <Text>ADD</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <View className="left">
                    <Text />
                </View>
                <View className="right">
                    <Text />
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: i did like that now but cannot run